# Correct way of using msbuild xmlpoke

Tags: xpath, msbuild, namespaces, prefix, xmlpoke

I am trying to set the value for  element if the  element value matches 
"ABB Automation Builder Platform.abpkg"

My script uses xmlpoke as below:

```
<XmlPoke 
                Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='x'  Uri='http://www150.abb.com/spaces/DAE-1/ProdDev/Shared%20Documents/40%20DAE%20Installer/Design/XML%20Descriptions/DAEInstaller_Description_StyleSheet' &gt;"
                Query="x:ProductUpdate/x:Packages/x:Package[x:FileName='ABB Automation Builder Platform.abpkg']/x:FileHash"
                XmlInputPath="Output\update.manifest"
                Value="Ajay Vishwakarma"/>
```

The xml I am trying to modify is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProductUpdate xmlns="http://www150.abb.com/spaces/DAE-1/ProdDev/Shared%20Documents/40%20DAE%20Installer/Design/XML%20Descriptions/DAEInstaller_Description_StyleSheet">
  <Strings>
    <Text id="1">
      <Neutral>ABB Automation Builder 1.0 \nService Release 1</Neutral>
      <Localized culture="en">ABB Automation Builder 1.0 \nService Release 1</Localized>
      <Localized culture="de">ABB Automation Builder 1.0 \nService Release 1</Localized>
      <Localized culture="fr">ABB Automation Builder 1.0 \nService Release 1</Localized>
      <Localized culture="es">ABB Automation Builder 1.0 \nService Release 1</Localized>
      <Localized culture="zh">ABB Automation Builder 1.0 \nService Release 1</Localized>
    </Text>
    <Text id="2">
      <Neutral>Information\ABB Automation Builder Upate Package V1_0_1Description_en.htm</Neutral>
      <Localized culture="en">Information\ABB Automation Builder Upate Package V1_0_1Description_en.htm</Localized>
      <Localized culture="de">Information\ABB Automation Builder Upate Package V1_0_1Description_de.htm</Localized>
      <Localized culture="fr">Information\ABB Automation Builder Upate Package V1_0_1Description_fr.htm</Localized>
      <Localized culture="es">Information\ABB Automation Builder Upate Package V1_0_1Description_es.htm</Localized>
      <Localized culture="zh">Information\ABB Automation Builder Upate Package V1_0_1Description_zh.htm</Localized>
    </Text>
  </Strings>
  <ReleaseType>ServicePack</ReleaseType>
  <ProductName>$1</ProductName>
  <Version>1.0.1</Version>
  <Description>$2</Description>
  <License>
    <Name>$3</Name>
    <ID>45668677876463</ID>
    <Description>$4</Description>
    <Version>1.0.1</Version>
    <DescriptionVersion>$5</DescriptionVersion>
    <DescriptionTypeVersion>1.0.0</DescriptionTypeVersion>
    <ToAccept>true</ToAccept>
  </License>
  <Copyright>$6</Copyright>
  <MinimumRequiredVersion>1.0.0</MinimumRequiredVersion>
  <Packages>
    <Package>
      <Name>ABB Automation Builder Platform Update Package</Name>
      <Description>ABB Automation Builder Platform Update Package</Description>
      <FileName>ABB Automation Builder Platform.abpkg</FileName>
      <FileHash>AjayVishwakarma</FileHash>
      <FileDownload>
      </FileDownload>
      <InstallerData>
        <Component>
          <Name>ABB Automation Builder Package Manager</Name>
          <ID>{F5B05B3F-9FA5-476E-BDD3-DB1397CABF4C}</ID>
          <Version>1.0.1.0</Version>
          <InstallAlways>true</InstallAlways>
        </Component>
      </InstallerData>
    </Package>
    <Package>
      <Name>PLC AC500 Update Package</Name>
      <Description>PLC AC500 Update Package</Description>
      <FileName>PLC - AC500.abpkg</FileName>
      <FileHash>8652d588d4c1fe70e0e06a9cf3e09193</FileHash>
      <FileDownload>
      </FileDownload>
      <InstallerData>
        <Component>
          <Name>Codesys</Name>
          <ID>{F8A33E2A-5B6A-474B-8ED2-293B4982D4E6}</ID>
          <Version>2.3.9.41</Version>
        </Component>
        <Component>
          <Name>Target Support Package</Name>
          <ID>{CC764263-BEF5-4060-AA49-0366AB2E868B}</ID>
          <Version>1.0.1.0</Version>
        </Component>
        <Component>
          <Name>Control Builder Plus documentation</Name>
          <ID>{484D63DB-1EB6-4F4F-851F-7F7D7D34A396}</ID>
          <Version>1.0.1.0</Version>
        </Component>
      </InstallerData>
    </Package>    
  </Packages>
</ProductUpdate>
```

XmlPoke task fails to update element value and gives message "Made 0 replacement(s)."
I have also tries passing query like

Query="//x:ProductUpdate/x:Packages/x:Package[x:FileName='ABB Automation Builder Platform.abpkg']/x:FileHash" OR 
Query=".//x:ProductUpdate/Packages/Package[FileName='ABB Automation Builder Platform.abpkg']/FileHash"

I want to know if I am doing it the wrong way? 
Please note that I don't want to make any changes in the namespace in my xml document.

Answer (score 1):

You're not crazy.

That (hex coded) spaces in the original xml document in the namespace are throwing things off.

I don't have an answer.

But here is a suggestion.

I always use XmlPeek and then "build up" the Query.

```
<XmlPeek Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='peanut' Uri='http://www150.abb.com/spaces/DAE-1/ProdDev/Shared%20Documents/40%20DAE%20Installer/Design/XML%20Descriptions/DAEInstaller_Description_StyleSheet'/&gt;"
     XmlInputPath=".\MyXmlFile.xml" 
     Query="//peanut:ProductUpdate">
    <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="Peeked" />
</XmlPeek>


<Message Text="@(Peeked)"/>
```

(Above with the XmlPeek, I have the top level Query "//ProductUpdate".
The Message @(Peeked) will show the xml fragment for there.
Then I can build up the query and see the results....and adjust as necessary. )

Anyway, back to the problem:

So the above will work ***IF*** you change the original Xml to be

```
<ProductUpdate xmlns="http://www150.abb.com/spaces/DAE-1/ProdDev/Shared Documents/40 DAE Installer/Design/XML Descriptions/DAEInstaller_Description_StyleSheet">
  <Strings>
```

But with the original Xml with the the Hex values for the spaces.......the above won't work.  :(

Anyway.   That stinks.  Its almost like the namespace (in the XmlPeek (or Poke) needs to be "double hexed encoded" or something.

Sorry, I gave it the college try.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a valid Namespace element. What you have is the opening tag, and not a self-closed element. 
Instead of:

```
<Namespace Prefix='x'  
     Uri='http://www150.abb.com/spaces/..../DAEInstaller_Description_StyleSheet'>
```

You need:

```
<Namespace Prefix='x'  
     Uri='http://www150.abb.com/spaces/..../DAEInstaller_Description_StyleSheet'/>
```